# How to add i18n support to an Android app?

Tags: android, react-native

Is it possible to add i18n support to the name of the app on the home screen? I'm currently setting the name of my app using a `strings.xml` file like this:

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">My App</string>
</resources>
```

And then in my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have something like this to set the name:

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I'd like to use a different value for `android:label` depending on the device's language, is this even possible?

Comment: This looks like native android to me. You can have separate `strings.xml`s in language specific `values` folders named like `values-en`, `values-fr`, `values-es`, etc. Then when you change the app language to `en`, all the `values-en` strings will be applied and so on for `fr` and `es`, etc. If you need to do this on iOS as well, you may need to add i18n, but I don't know if changing the language in iOS is possible in a way similar to android.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will try to find the solution by following your advice. Do you have an example by any chance?

Comment: Try this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework